# What is the best way to access a REST API from a webclient?

Tags: php, javascript, http, rest, proxy

I want to develop a website which has to communicate with a given RESTful API over HTTP GET, POST, PUT & DELETE a lot.
Now while I have some knowledge in JavaScript, I don't know much about PHP and other possible languages. 
Before digging into any new concepts of web-programming, I want to know what is the best way to do it?
I already realised that pure JavaScript is not appropriate due to cross-domain scripting restrictions. I tried to use a basic PHP proxy but that doesn't seem to work for all four request types.

During my research I stumbled over several keywords... like

- JavaScript with Proxy
- PHP, symfony framework, Doctrine
- Ruby on Rails
- etc.

What are your experiences regarding this topic? Do you have suggestions for a rather low-skilled web-developer like me in order to set up a basic RESTful client? (Can't be really that difficult, can it?)

Thanks a lot,
Matthias

Comment: It is possible to get PHP Curl working for the request types you mentioned

Comment: You might want to look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org), which is a server-side JavaScript programming environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the JavaScript with PHP proxy option. In PHP, you can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [HTTP_Request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-request.php) to do the request with all 4 methods (not sure what went wrong when you tried it, perhaps you could elaborate on that).

There are many PHP rest clients out there that wrap around cURL or HTTP_Request. Here are a few to get you started:

- https://github.com/educoder/pest
- https://github.com/tonychang/PhpRestClient
- http://code.google.com/p/easyrest/
- http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/building-a-simple-http-client-with-php-a-rest-client/
- https://github.com/tcdent/php-restclient

Comment: I tried Ben Alman's [Simple PHP Proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) and was only able to issue GET requests. Does it support the other three as well?

Comment: I have never worked with it, but from a quick look at the documentation, it doesn't look like it's intended to support all 4 methods. You're better off writing your own using cURL or one of the links I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Check out CodeIgniter along with Phil Sturgeon's REST Server and REST Client libraries.